# If $a_0\in R$ is a unit, then  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k x^k$ is a unit in $R[[x]]$

Tags: ring-theory, power-series

Let $R$ a ring, and let $$\displaystyle R[[x]]=\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k x^k\;\middle\vert\; a_k\in R\right\}$$ with addition and multiplication as defined for polynomials.  We have that $R[[x]]$ is a ring containing $R[x]$ as a subring.

How to prove that if $a_0\in R$ is a unit, then  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k x^k$ is a unit in $R[[x]]$?

Answer (score 16):

Let $a=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\in R[[x]]$, where $a_0$ is a unit. We want to construct some $b=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k\in R[[x]]$ such that $ab=1$, or after expanding,
$$ab=a_0b_0+(a_1b_0+a_0b_1)x+\cdots=1+0x+0x^2+\cdots$$
We therefore need $b_0=a_0^{-1}$ (recall that $a_0$ is a unit). We want to have $a_1b_0+a_0b_1=0$, so our only choice for $b_1$ is $$b_1=\frac{-a_1b_0}{a_0}=-a_1a_0^{-2}.$$ We want $a_2b_0+a_1b_1+a_0b_2=0$, so we must have $$b_2=\frac{-a_2b_0-a_1b_1}{a_0}=-a_2a_0^{-2}+a_1^2a_0^{-3}.$$
Prove that, by continuing this process, you get a $b$ such that $ab=1$.

Comment: Zev when write $b_1=-a_1a_{0}^{-1}$  you use that $R$ is conmutative to find  $b_1$?

Comment: That's true (I'm just accustomed to working with commutative rings) but it isn't too hard to modify what I've written to be correct for non-commutative rings too.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ to invert $\,\rm a-xf,\,$  scale it by $\,\rm \color{#c00}{b=a^{-1}}\,$ so it's $\rm\color{darkorange}{monic}$, then use a $\rm\color{#0a0}{geometric \ series}$

$\rm\displaystyle\ \qquad 1\: =\: (a-xf)(b-xg)\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{ab=1}$
$\qquad\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \displaystyle\rm\frac{1}{a-xf}\ = \dfrac{b}{\color{#c00}b(\color{#c00}a-xf)}\ =\ \frac{b}{\color{darkorange}{\bf 1}-bxf}\ =\ b\:(\overbrace{1+bxf+(bxf)^2+(bxf)^3+\:\cdots\:}^{\large \color{#0a0}{\text{geometric series}}})$

which converges since  $\rm \,(bxf)^n\,$ has order $\to \infty\,$ as $\rm\,n\to\infty\,$ (see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/29549/242) for much more on the (oft-misunderstood) topic of convergence of *formal* power series).

[Corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116897/242) $ $ When $R$ is a field the fraction field of $R[[x]]$ has Laurent form, i.e. every fraction can be written with denominator $\rm\,x^n,\,$ by $\rm\,g/h = g/(x^n(a\!-\!xf)) = gh'/x^n\,$ for $\rm\, h'\! = (a\!-\!xf)^{-1}\!\in R[[x]]$

Comment: Bill as I use this for my exercise?

Comment: @Andres I'm not sure what your question means. If you're asking if the above is rigorous, then, yes, it is, as long as you understand that the RHS converges since the order of $\rm\:(xf)^n\to\infty$ as $\rm\:n\to\infty.\:$ [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/29549/242) for more on convergence of formal power series.

Comment: @Andres: To use this answer for the exercise, let $a-xf$ be your power series, where $a=a_0$, $b$ is its inverse, and $f=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^{k-1}$ (I use more or less the same idea in my answer).

Comment: @Downvoter If something is not clear then please feel welcome to ask questions and I will be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to get the geometric series involved. We can write

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{a_0}\frac{1}{1+\underbrace{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_0^{-1}a_kx^k\right)}_{u(x)}}. \tag{$\circ$}$$

Now $x|u(x)$, so in the $l$-adic topology the sequence $u(x),u(x)^2,u(x)^3,\cdots$ converges to $0$, or equivalently the terms contributed to the coefficient of a $x^n$ from these powers is gauranteed to be finite for all $n$. Thus if you expand $(\circ)$ in a geometric series, the element of $R[[x]]$ it converges to will be a legitimate multiplicative inverse (by the usual algebra establishing the geo sum formula).