# Prove $\alpha \in R[[x]]$ is a unit iff $a_0 \in R$ is a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, power-series

> Prove $\alpha \in R[[x]]$ is a unit iff $a_0 \in R$ is a unit.

$"\Rightarrow"$ suppose $\alpha \in R[[x]]$ is a unit, where $\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$

then there exists an inverse $\beta = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n$

stuck at this spot,

$(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n)(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(a_kb_{n-k}))x^n$

A little mixed up on how this becomes $1 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e_nx^n$ where $e_0 =1, e_{n>0} = 0$ and why that would make $a_0b_0 = 1$ which would make $a_0 \in R$ a unit. I haven't tried the other direction yet.

**EDIT**

Maybe I get it, because we assumed this sum is a unit then its inverse exists and so the $x^0=1$ and all $a_ib_i=1$ thus $a_0b_0=1$ which gives $a_0$ is a unit in $R$

Comment: This looks like [a duplicate of this older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/160471/11619). Oliver, do remember to search the site before and also immediately after posting! The site SW will compile a list of *Related* questions to the right margin. I picked this from there (consequently promoting it to the list of *Linked* questions). Leaving it to the others to decide, whether this needs to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Not *quite* a duplicate, I'd say, since this question asks for "iff" whereas the other only goes in one direction.  If anything, *that* question should logically be subsumed under this one.  But Jyrki''s advice about searching is most excellent.  Cheers to all!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We know (if $\beta = \alpha^{-1}$) that 
$$ 1 = \sum_n e_n x^n = \sum_n \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} x^n $$
That is 
$$ \forall n \ge 0 : e_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} $$
especially (let $n = 0$): 
$$ 1 = e_0 = a_0 b_0 $$
(hence $a_0$ is a unit).

For the other direction, suppose $a_0$ is a unit with inverse $b_0 := a_0^{-1}$. We want to define $\beta = \sum_n b_n x^n$ such that 
$$ 0 = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}, \quad n \ge 1 $$
This is achieved by inductively defining 
$$ b_n := -a_0^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_{n-k} $$
Then $\beta := \sum_n b_n x^n$ is an inverse to $\alpha$.

Comment: I know that for a polynomial to be a unit it is necessary that the constant term is unit and the other coefficients are nilpotent. But one can replicate the same inductive steps and show that "if the constant term is unit then the polynomial is a unit". What am I missing?

Comment: @Babai defining $b_n$ this way makes the $n$-th coefficient zero but creates higher order terms in $\alpha\beta$ which are not zero, this gets resolved by choosing an appropriate coefficient of $\beta$ for that order term. With finite degree polynomials there is no choice for that higher order term. Try defining the "inverse" this way for an easy polynomial e.g. of degree 2. It will become clear.

Answer (score 4):

$\alpha \beta =1$ means $(a_0 + a_1 x+\cdots)(b_0 + b_1 x+ \cdots)=1+0x+\cdots$ so $a_0b_0+ (a_1b_0+a_0 b_1)x+\cdots=1+0x+\cdots$ therefore $a_0b_0=1$